# Does e-commerce platform matter for branding

Tags: ecommerce, marketing

The place I work is now looking into developing a new e-commerce site on the Magento platform. Magento will fill all of our needs.

I was just wondering if it is in anyway unprofessional doing it this way (Impression is something we are really worried about), will people who visit the site look at our business different knowing we used Magento or any other e-commerce platform.

There are ways to find out. I use [Chrome Sniffer](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-sniffer/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae) to find out what platforms are used to develop each site, there are other tools available for different browsers.

Bottom-line: Will an e-commerce platform affect the trust in my brand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People who visit your site by and large care not at all what technologies you use to build it. They are blissfully unaware of that, and part of your job is to make sure they remain so.

Comment: Customers only care about the look, feel, response and workflow. More important actually to you is the backend and whether it functions with **your** workflow and interoperates with your ERP software. If I had a choice of two systems that gave _**identical results**_ for the customers, I'd examine closely the administrative and interoperability side with a fine tooth comb and go with the system that fit my needs best from this standpoint.

Comment: Good advice, this. Users care about UX. If the app is easy to use, gives relevant feedback, and is responsive, they're happy. Developers need to care about a much wider range of things, interoperability chief among them.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the platform you use when building eCommerce websites for customers? If so yes it matters. If the shopping cart software you use is difficult for them to manage products, variations, and import products they'll only find this out once they begin working with the cart long after your front end design is finished.

Do they get print catalogs as well as CSV's from vendors for their products? Will they have to update hundreds of products and thousands of variations each year when new products come out. How easy can they do this? Either way there's no reason not to go with magento. It's easily customizeable and has plenty of addons ready to go both free and paid. IMO you'd be hurting yourself not using it or knowing how it works at least.

Comment: This is not my issue, I have all the features I need & the use of it will be easy. My question is, if I get the same exact site result with two different e-commerce platforms, can make a difference in their trust in my company.

Comment: I think @Anagio is trying to point out that the overhead created by a backend that doesn't function with your business drives down your ROI pretty quickly and overcomes the sweetness of a pretty public customer website. Make sure the backend isn't pouring sand in your businesses gearbox.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Thanks for the explanation. Anagio has very good points, but this was not my question.

Comment: There are those looking into developing and those who have come out the other side and will give you answers to questions you haven't asked yet because you've not experienced the misfit. It's known as experience.

Comment: @FiascoLabs You are right. He is trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, this does not matter. What is really important for the client is the quality of the website, its design, its functionalities and also very important point secure transactions and data transfer.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Are you a marketer or it's known it doesn't affect? I do judge sometimes based on the platform used (that is why I asked).

Comment: Because it's in your interest to know what platform is used, but you have that insight from other data the customer doesn't often know or care about.

Answer (score 0):

The platform an e-commerce site is built it should not matter to the customer, for the simple reason that if an online store is developed properly, it won't be apparent without doing some digging, exactly which platform is being used.

Any platform that ticks all these boxes is as good as any other as far as the user's judgement is concerned.

1. Looks professional (custom themes mean ANY platform can look amateur or professional)
2. Is secure.
3. Good performance.
4. Good user experience by default.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe trust building and brand management depends on the quality of service you are offering to your clients and in your case, it would be the level of User Experience that you are offering to your prospects. It’s a common fact that nobody cares about the platform on which the website is based on till he or she is getting whatever is needed or expected. Magento anyways is one of the best ecommerce platforms to ever advent the web development world.

Answer (score 0):

No,  e-commerce platform doesn't affect the trust in our brand. I will tell you how ? Customer only love the way website designed. Customer prefer user friendly websites , secure, responsive design, beautiful theme, browser compatible. These are the things customer noticed.